# How secure is 'Plain Old RSA'

Tags: rsa

Let's say I use RSA encryption, it's 2048 bits and I use a simple character padding scheme, every character is turned into a 3 digit number and strung together, then encrypted. Saying that no message will be below 40 characters, ending up in a 120 digit number, how insecure is this?

Edit: The public exponent is as small as it could be, let's say 7 in this case

Comment: with what public exponent? ​ ​ ​

Comment: The public exponent is 7 or more

Comment: I could pretty easily identify $40 \times 3$ digits set to zero, so it's not secure by that observation alone. Repeating the plaintext would also be an issue.

Comment: What do you mean 40 * 3 digits "Set to zero?" And I don't understand repeating the plaintext, I'm 14 by the way.